# drawImage not drawing

Tags: javascript, typeerror, drawimage

I am trying to draw crop an image and draw it onto the canvas  but when ran in the browser the canvas remains white. no errors appear.

```
var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = 'sprite.png';
imgSprite.addEventListener('load', init, false);

function init(){
    drawBg();

}
function drawBg() {
    var sourceX =0;
    var sourceY =0;
    var sourceWidth =800;
    var sourceHeight =500;
    var destWidth =800;
    var destHeight =500;
    var destX =0;
    var destY =0;
    //ctxBg.clearRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
    ctxBg.drawImage(imgSprite, sourceX,sourceY,sourceWidth,sourceHeight,
        destWidth,destHeight,destX,destY);
}
```

Comment: What line is the TypeError on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last four parameters to drawImage are in the wrong order. It should be:

```
ctxBg.drawImage(imgSprite, sourceX,sourceY,sourceWidth,sourceHeight,
        destX,destY,destWidth,destHeight); // x,y before width,height
```

See [CanvasRenderingContext2D drawImage()](http://www.javascripture.com/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage) for all the overloads and interactive examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter set is not matching any of the available parameter sets for [drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage%28%29)

```
ctxBg.drawImage(imgSprite, 0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z6Gja/)

Comment: I am following the parameters set by w3 for using drawImage, I thought the extra 0,0 parameters at the end of my code was telling the program to start drawing from canvas 0,0. I am trying to clip a part of my sprite sheet and only draw that section of my sprite sheet onto my canvas. How do I do this?

Comment: @rrcm what is the starting cordinate of the image you want to use

Comment: @rrcm look at [this example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/) in how to crop the image

Comment: @rrcm set by w3whom? W3Consortium would never issue something that isn't correct. If you meant W3Schools (totally unrelated), that's a terrible resource..